# How to use forceChatter:feed with a record?

Tags: lightning, aura, chatter, chatter-feed

How to show the Chatter feed for a record in a custom component? I am trying to use the forceChatter:feed type="Record" but it is not giving the correct results for the record?
Can anyone help me with the implementation of forceChatter:publisher and forceChatter: feed in the custom aura/LWC component on a record which has chatter enabled.

This is when <forceChatter:feed type="Record"/> is used.
[image]

This is actual feed on Record.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Could you share the code you have tried so far and give more details what is the issue with the results ?

Comment: I am using below code and getting these results: 
<forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
<forceChatter:feed type="Record"/>
It is not giving chatter feed for the record from which it is being called.
If I use: 
<forceChatter:feed type="Company"/>
I am getting all the feed even the private groups I am part of. 
I need to show the Chatter feed of the record from where this component is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I used the attribute subjectid and passed the recordId to it. :) It will give the Chatter feed of that particular record.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue I fixed it using the feedDesign Attribte like below:

`<forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.recordId}" feedDesign="DEFAULT"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you must post just one FeedItem, and have to post it to the CollaborationGroup on your instead of showing a chatter:feed, which will just show just Chatter related to that record, you could use the chatter:newsFeed tag instead. This will show all Chatter relevant for the running user. That way, if the running User is a member of the CollaborationGroup to which you posted the FeedItem, the running User will, when viewing this see the recent Chatter posts for the CollaborationGroup, as well as any Chatter posts for the record in context, or Chatter posts directed at them.

[A Chatter Feed related to a Record as well as a Chatter Group](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/a-chatter-feed-related-to-a-record-as-well-as-a-chatter-group)